# R list appending i.e. appending to an existing list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-structures

Now, normally I would use JSON or `data.frame`s, but my course specifically asks to store a name and Movie table in a named `list`.  I struggle to append to the `list`.

Here is my implementation:

```
demoList <- list(
    name = c("Doug", "Steven"), 
    movies = list( c("Gremlins", "Cars", "1984"), c("Freaky Friday", "Hitchhiker's Guide")))
```

i.e. I have Hector, and his movies would be ("Jurassic Park", "Jaws".)

When I try to add Herbert to the name vector it overwrites my vector.
i.e.

```
demoList$[5] <- Hector
```

Appending to `demoList$movies` would probably follow the same conventions.

All of the R forums I searched created new `$variables` for appending, so would my issue be that I chose the wrong representation of the data in the named list?

Comment: I don't understand your `list` structure. *How* and *where* (in the `list` hierarchy) do you want to add entries? This doesn't seem to be a good structure for storing names and movie details.

Comment: That may be my issue.  I'd image you need two vectors.  One to store names and another to store movies and the number of names would map to the number of movies.  What would be a better way to store that info?  I experimented with a few other ideas; namely having a multiple name entires

Comment: One way would be to store name and (a list of) movies in a separate nested `list`. Then your  `demoList` contains entries that are `list`s, one for each unique name. You said you're familiar with JSON; perhaps edit your post to include the structure you have in mind in JSON format; it is very easy to conceptually and practically translate JSON to a (nested) `list` structure. I am still unsure how and where you want to add entries; perhaps also include your expected output (as JSON or a `list` mock-up).

Comment: I suggest using something like `d<-data.frame(name=c("Doug","Doug",...),movie=c("Gremlins","Cars",...))`. It's easy enough to grab all of Doug's stuff: `d[d$name=="Doug",,drop=F]`, it allows simple appending with `cbind.data.frame`, and I find "tall formats" like this to extend and adapt very easily.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `Map` to `append`

```
demoList <- Map(append, demoList, list("Hector", list(c("Jurassic Park", "Jaws"))))
demoList
#$name
#[1] "Doug"   "Steven" "Hector"

#$movies
#$movies[[1]]
#[1] "Gremlins" "Cars"     "1984"    

#$movies[[2]]
#[1] "Freaky Friday"      "Hitchhiker's Guide"

#$movies[[3]]
#[1] "Jurassic Park" "Jaws"
```

Comment: Thank You! This map is just what I needed.  It works fine.  You sir, are a wizard.